# getting the out put as undefined while using <a href=""></a>

Tags: ajax, html, jquery-mobile

This is my exibitview.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" manifest="health.cache">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>Video Campaign View</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery-mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/base.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="Styles/portrait.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="Styles/landscape.css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-mobile-old.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ajaxExhibitXmlParser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/easypaginate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h2>My Campaign Home Page</h2>
        </header>
        <div id="section_main">
            <article class="main-content">
                <ul class="exihibit">
                </ul>
            </article>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my ajaxExhibitXmlParser.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            //url: "5_section_nature-1.xml",
            url: "xmls/exhibit.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('exhibits').each(function(){
                    $(this).find('exihibit').each(function(){

                    var vmediaurl = $(this).find('redirecturl').text();
                    var mediaurl =  vmediaurl ;
                    var medianame = $(this).find('name').text();
                    var mediadesc = $(this).find('description').text();
                    var vmediathumbnail = $(this).find('icon').text();
                    var mediathumbnail ="'" + vmediathumbnail + "'";
                    localStorage.setItem(vmediathumbnail, vmediathumbnail);
                    localStorage.setItem(mediathumbnail, mediathumbnail);
                    localStorage.setItem(mediaurl, mediaurl);
                    localStorage.setItem(medianame, medianame);
                    localStorage.setItem(mediadesc, mediadesc);



                        $('<li></li>').html('<a href="http://localhost:8080/PatientsHealth/Images/ajax-loader.gif"><img width="300" height="250" src='+localStorage.getItem(mediathumbnail)+' alt="poster image"><span class="exihibit"><p>'+localStorage.getItem(medianame)+'</p><p>'+localStorage.getItem(mediadesc)+'</p></span></a>').appendTo('ul.exihibit');
                    });

                });
                jQuery(function($){

                    $('ul').easyPaginate({
                        step:2
                    });

                });

            }
        });
```

When i click on the image of exihibitview.html page i am getting error as undefined if I refresh page by using F5 i am able to get the image. Can any one plaese help me solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't look right to me:

```
$('<li></li>').html('<a href="http://localhost....gif"><img width="300" height="250" src='+localStorage.getItem(mediathumbnail)+' alt="poster image"><span class="exihibit"><p>'+localStorage.getItem(medianame)+'</p><p>'+localStorage.getItem(mediadesc)+'</p></span></a>').appendTo('ul.exihibit');
```

In jQuery, I'm fairly certain you can't select  list item with `$('<li></li>')`. You have to use something like `$('li')`.

Furthermore, it's not such a great idea semantically to have a `paragraph` inside a `span`.

It looks as though you're trying to do something like this:

```
$('ul.exhibit').append('<li><a href="..."><img src="..." alt="..." /></a></li>');
```

Comment: +1, but maybe he wants to create the li element and append it to ul.exhibit?

Comment: can u please help how to use  this line with both <li> ans </li>

Comment: I have changed the code as you suggested but i am getting same error

Comment: Do you have an example of what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: actually the link should be redirected to next html page but i placed image url in the 'href' .I am getting the same error as undefined while using this but on reload i able to get the page

Answer (score 0):

use rel="external" in  tag

```
$('ul.exhibit').append('<li><a rel="external" href="..."><img src="..." alt="..." /></a></li>');
```